# Android Keyboard Language issue

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to change the keyboard language programatically when user selects `EditText` field.

i.e.: When user clicks on `EditText`, by default English language keyboard pops up.
But I want the Arabic keyboard to open by default...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to change the keyboard settings for the user programmatically. The only thing you can do is advise the user to change it and help it to do so. For instance, this will show a dialog for them to change keyboard:

```
private void showInputMethodPicker() {
    InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    if (imeManager != null) {
        imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_possible_im_picker, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but i am developing educational app for kids, so its not possible for them to select keyboard, and understand these things.
I think now the solution is to build up own keyboard..
any suggestions on how to do it..??

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use EditorInfo hintLocales:
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#hintLocales

From https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79549909